Counting the number of posets with fixed dimension
I'm reading through a few of Trotter's papers on dimension and cardinality over certain posets, and I was curious about some combinatorial questions on posets with fixed dimension.In particular, what are some nice lower/upper bounds for the number of posets over $n$ elements with some dimension $d$? Here, take the dimension of a poset $P$ to be the minimum number of linear extensions whose intersection is $P$.
The question was asked here but there were no answers. Are there any references for this problem? Thanks!

Are you familiar with his book Combinatorics and Partially Ordered Sets: Dimension Theory (1992)? You may find some leads there.
